# Why does Lelouch speak English?

Tags: code-geass

> Lelouch Vi Brittania commands you...

Everyone who watched *Code Geass* heard this phrase, in both the dubbed version and original Japanese version.

My question is: Why, in the original Japanese version of *Code Geass*, does Lelouch speak in English when he uses his Geass?

Comment: Uh, I'm pretty sure that Lelouch never says "Lelouch vi Brittania commands you" in English in the Japanese version. His typical line when issuing a geass is 「ルルーシュ・ヴィ・ブリタニアが命じる」 _Lelouch vi Brittania ga meijiru_ (which does mean "Lelouch vi Brittania commands you").

Comment: Just like @senshin said, he speaks normal japanese there. No english involved at all.

Comment: I don't see why this question should receive so many downvotes. *ga meijiru* does sound like *commands you* spoken in a Japanese accent.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is why does he speak English in the Japanese version? Well, he does not.

The key sentence he says is

> Lelouch Vi Britannia ga meijiru: [senshin's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7994/why-does-lelouch-speak-english#comment9728_7994) states it's "ga" and not "ha"

Which means "Lelouch Vi Britannia commands you", in Japanese.

Answer (score -4):

He's Britannian thats why he speaks in english 
and i think coz its more catchy to use the english version . just an opinion.